# Does participation on a per-site meta count toward completing a commitment to that site?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stackexchange-2.0, beta-phase, commitment-fulfillment

Do my questions/participation on both X.stackexchange and meta.X.stackexchange count when evaluating whether I've hit my commitment mark for the site ?

Comment: Since meta questions/answers don't even award you points in beta, I would think not....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only participation on X.stackexchange.com counts toward fulfilling your commitment there.

However, if you would like to be a moderator on the site, know that we heavily weight participation on meta.X.stackexchange.com when evaluating suitable candidates.

So there are other benefits to participating on meta.

Comment: don't forget to mention the means to better shape the site

Comment: @JeffAtwood is this still true 2+ years later? There's been some discussion elsewhere that it may have changed. Is there any official answer to this question? Seems that lots of people are curious about it. It could perhaps be considered a frequently-asked-question.

Comment: I agree that it would be nice if this were answered directly in the FAQ.