# Does Fulfillment take into account Meta posts?

Tags: support, area-51, per-site-meta, commitment-fulfillment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does participation on a per-site meta count toward completing a commitment to that site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59222/does-participation-on-a-per-site-meta-count-toward-completing-a-commitment-to-th)

Does Area 51 take participation on the meta site (e.g. http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com) when evaluating whether a commitment (e.g. http://webapps.stackexchange.com) has been fulfilled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, per-site metas are not counted in any way toward fulfilling an Area 51 site commitment.

Comment: Boo! (sniffles)