# Do meta questions and answers count toward site commitment?

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0, beta-phase, per-site-meta, commitment-fulfillment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Fulfillment take into account Meta posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62352/does-fulfillment-take-into-account-meta-posts)

Lately I find myself as involved in a site's meta as the actual site.  Do those posts count toward my commitment, or do I need to be more involved in the parent site?