# How to undo a commit to a Area 51 proposal?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-fulfillment

[I commited](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/30610/roflcoptr) to 3 different Area51 proposals. Now I saw that Sports is in the commitment phase and I want to commit there too. But the limit is set to 3. So how can I uncommit from a Area51 proposal?

Comment: This may be by-design. Wouldn't be much of a commitment if you could undo it just like that.

Comment: Yes that´s true, but I comitted to the site over 200 days ago. In this time, a lot has changed and the site is still in beta side, and now I found a new, more intersting site. I think it is valid to chance mind after 200 days of waiting.

Answer (score 19):

You can [undo a commitment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104198/how-to-undo-a-commit-to-a-area-51-proposal/104200#104200) at any time as long as the site doesn't exist, in other words as long as the proposal is still in the commitment phase. Once a beta site is created, it is time to follow through on your commitment.

Looking at [your profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/30610/roflcoptr), you are committed to three proposals that are in the beta stage. If you want to commit to other sites, you must first fulfill your commitment to at least one of the existing sites. You would do that by posting questions and answers on the sites.

If you don't choose to participate, you're proving that you weren't serious about your commitments. So it's understandable that you shouldn't be allowed to commit to more sites — if you didn't follow through in the past, you're unlikely to follow through in the future. Nonetheless, you will be given a reprieve. Once a site leaves the beta phase, you will get back the associated commitment slot. Until then, your help is still needed to build the site.

Comment: Does Meta activity count towards fulfilled commitment?

Comment: @Ambo100 No. [Does participation on a per-site meta count toward completing a commitment to that site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59222)

Comment: "If you don't choose to participate, you're proving that you weren't serious about your commitments." This is one possibility. Another possibility is that the other participants close your questions because they think that the subject area that made you commit should not be part of the new site.

Answer (score 11):

1. First, uncommit. Just go to the proposal you want uncommit from and press "Uncommit" (this only works for proposals in the *commitment* phase, not for proposals in a *beta* phase):

   [image]
2. Commit to the other proposal. Press "Commit".

In the first part of Area 51's life it was not possible to uncommit from a proposal until the public beta was over (this could take a loooong time if the proposal moved at glacial speed through the different phases), but it is possible now.

If *all* three committed-to proposals are in a *beta* phase you either have to wait until the beta phase ends for one of them or follow through on the commitment (by posing questions, answering questions, commenting, etc.) for a proposal.

Comment: Did you photoshopped that?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: no, I just used the good old trusty built-in [Microsoft Paint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint_%28software%29).

Comment: I was talking about the uncommit button. In my case I can´t see this button

Comment: @Roflcoptr: is the proposal you are trying to uncommit from in the commitment phase? Perhaps it is not possible if the proposal is in a beta phase (private or public)? Can you check the state of all three proposals you are committed to?

Comment: +1 for freehand circles :)

Comment: Not really, I´m just following Sports. But I want to commit to it. The sites I want to uncommit are all in the public beta phase.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: I am sorry, my mistake. It seems it is not possible to uncommit from a proposal in a beta phase (as all three of your commitments.). I have updated my answer.

Comment: So if you referring to the first time of Area 51, so it also applies for sites that were proposed then?

Comment: Ok I saw your new edit. I think it is not really a good system. At least 2 sites Ißve committed too are in public beta for over 200 days and the stats arenßt really good. So I can wait forever...

Comment: Yes, I think it depends in the state of a proposal, not when the proposal was born.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: You don't have to wait forever, there is a way out! Participate sufficiently in the beta phase of a proposal, and you will be relieved of the commitment (and get the *[Upholder](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/210/upholder)* badge on Area 51). For instance, I did it for the *[Astronomy](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/)* site and got the badge about 50 days into the beta phase. "Participate sufficiently" means answering questions, commenting, etc. How much is needed is a secret (voting on your answers is probably a factor) - you just have keep to working on it.

Comment: When you commit, I believe it says that it requires a combination of 10 questions and answers.

Answer (score 5):

I've been checking your profile out, the best way for you is to fulfill a commitment. It looks like the Code Review one would be the best one to fulfill in your case. Ask/answer 4 more questions, and you'll be done in the next day or two. Then you'll be able to commit to another one.