# How can I un-commit from a proposal that is in the beta stage?

Tags: support, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to undo a commit to a Area 51 proposal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104198/how-to-undo-a-commit-to-a-area-51-proposal)

I have some commitments that have reached beta that I want to un-commit to.

Comment: Dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104198/how-to-undo-a-commit-to-a-area-51-proposal